# Exportar dados do mysql para csv

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Estou tentando fazer a exportação de dados específicos de um banco de um cliente para csv, pesquisei na internet e falaram que iria conseguir usando o código abaixo.

```
SELECT * FROM escola
INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/orders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Porém quando eu utilizo aparece: "error SQL 1045" Access denied for user 'forms'@'%'(using password: YES)". Fui pesquisar no proprio forum da mysql, e achei uma informação dizendo que eu teria que entrar como administrador no banco para alterar o usuário com problema, porem eu não consigo ter esse acesso. Teria outra forma para realizar a exportação? ou para resolver esse erro?

Estou pensando em fazer com python, utilizando vários selects e tratando os dados para a criação do csv, porem acho que é um esforço desnecessário.

Estou usando o HeidiSQL 9.5.0

Comment: Uma pergunta: o diretório aceita gravação; as permissões estão adequadas? Ou o arquivo orders.csv já não está aberto?

Comment: Sobre o diretorio, sim, estaria acessando o banco que está no servidor do cliente e salvaria no diretorio em minha máquina. Possuo permissão de inserir e apagar no banco, porem não tenho permissão de alterar tabelas, criar e etc... O arquivo orders.csv seria o arquivo csv q eu quero que o heidi crie para mim

Comment: Acredito que salvamento em sua máquina não seja possível por segurança de rede.Talvez só possa salvar num diretório do servidor, mas não tenho certeza.

Comment: Teria outra forma para fazer a exportação sem ter que usar o python?